# How to remove Content-Type & Content-Length headers added by retrofit?

Tags: android, http-headers, retrofit, content-type

I am using retrofit to make API calls, however the server doesn't allow Content-Type and Content-Length as request headers for some APIs.

The retrofit will auto add those two headers when make the call, any solution to prevent this behavior?

PS: interceptor to modify/remove header didn't work bcos Content-Type and Content-Length are added after retrofit built.

PPS: I've forked the Retrofit lib and tried to customise it but couldn't find where it did the trick to add the headers. Anyone knows where retrofit did the trick?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: **@IsmailKhan** Eventually I used OkHttpClient for that special API call.
`Response response = client.newCall(prepareRequest(theCustomRequestBody)).execute();`

Comment: Funnily enough I did exactly the same!

Comment: Because I really couldn't find another way though
╮(╯_╰)╭

Comment: @ThorChiam did you got any solution. I am facing same issue.

Comment: Did anyone find any solution?